# Global Variables as Function Parameters

Tags: r, dataframe, global

In an R project, we have a global dataframe `df` that is to be used inside a function `my_func()`. The dataframe will not be changed, but it will be used as a "read-only" table.

Can you please assist me, on, what is the best practice:

1. Include the dataframe in the parameters of the function, as in

   ```
   my_func(df)
   {
   a <- df[1,2]
   }
   ```

   OR
2. Not include it in the parameters, just use it (read it) in the function body, as in

   ```
   my_func()
   {
   a <- df[1,2]
   }
   ```

Comment: That's easy. It's always better (safer) to pass it as a parameter than to rely on scoping. (There are exceptions, but they are rare.)

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world, data enters a function as an argument and leaves it as a return value. That is a good principle. Besides it is prefereable for code reuse. Right now you may be conviced, that you will only ever call this code on `df` (bad name by the way, as there is a function calles `df` already in R and that can lead to terrible error messages).

The only exception from this rule, and the reason, why `<<-` exist(*), may rarely be performance.

**However** in the read-only case, there are no performance gains, as R does behave cleverly.

Will will need to install the `microbenchmark` package for the following code to run:

```
expl <- data.frame(a = rep("Hello world.", 1e8),
                   b = rep(1, 1e8))


fun1 <- function(dataframe) return(sum(dataframe$b))

fun2 <- function() return(sum(expl$b))


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(fun1(expl), fun2())
```

Try it and you will see, that there is no performance gain in `fun2`over `fun1`, even though the dataframe has considerable size.

**Edit**:

(*) as I have learned from Konrad Rudolph's comment below, `<<-` can be usefull, when giving data to the parent, not necessarily the global namespace. Very interesting read even if not strictly on topic here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#mutable-state

Comment: This answer starts out well but over-emphasises performance. In most cases the concern isn’t performance but readability and maintainability. In the same vein, the (by far) predominant usage of `<<-` has nothing to do with performance, it’s due to assignment to the parent scope in closures.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thank you for the additional point. I am by no means an expert of `<<-` usage but I tend to claim that assignment to parent scope is a really bad idea if it is motivated by code maintainability. It should be obvious to the maintainer, which variables go into and are affected by a function and I see global namespace as the dominant way to hide that instead of making it obvious. I am not shure, whether or how much personal taste plays a role in that. So far I lived well avoiding `<<-` altogether and can only see me change that in future if performance forced me to.

Comment: Parent scope ≠ global environment, hence why I said “in closures”. This is for example what the now-obsolete RC classes did, but the same situation occurs any time you have a mutable closure. It’s not super common but it definitely occurs (for more info, check out [*Advanced R* on this topic](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#mutable-state)).

Comment: Thank you for the interesting read. I can now see how changing the parent scope without changing the global environment can be useful when the parent scope is small enough for the programmer to keep control, as in the counter function generator. I have learned more from you than I tried to teach the OP! Also, I did not know RC classes were obsolete, but I will search and read. If you have a more differentiating answer to the original question, whether eleni1982 should reference data from the global namespace, I  look forward to reading and upvoting it.